# How do I compile Tomcat mod_jk on a MacBook Pro M1 chip?

Tags: apache, coldfusion, homebrew, apple-m1, mod-jk

I have Homebrew Apache installed and trying to connect Coldfusion Server 2016 with Tomcat mod_jk.

I downloaded the source code from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi

I followed the directions to compile it, tried few different ways, but when I get to the "make" command, I keep getting the same error:

```
In file included from jk_ajp12_worker.c:26:
In file included from ./jk_ajp12_worker.h:26:
In file included from ./jk_logger.h:26:
In file included from ./jk_global.h:340:
./jk_types.h:56:2: error: Can not determine the proper size for pid_t
#error Can not determine the proper size for pid_t
 ^
./jk_types.h:62:2: error: Can not determine the proper size for pthread_t
#error Can not determine the proper size for pthread_t
 ^
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [jk_ajp12_worker.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

These are the different commands I've tried to compile:

```
./configure --with-apxs=/opt/homebrew/bin/apxs
./configure CFLAGS='-arch arm64e' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch arm64e' --with-apxs=/opt/homebrew/bin/apxs
./configure CFLAGS='-arch arm64e' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch arm64e' --with-apxs=/opt/homebrew/bin/apxs --host=arm
```

I recently got this new MacBook Pro 16" and migrated everything over from my 2017 MacBook Pro (Intel chip). I was running stock Apache with Coldfusion Server 2016, but when I tried to start up Apache on the new MacBook, it didn't like my mod_jk.so file and threw an error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 542 of /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/mod_jk.conf: 
Cannot load /Applications/ColdFusion2016/config/wsconfig/2/mod_jk.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/ColdFusion2016/config/wsconfig/2/mod_jk.so, 0x000A): 
tried: '/Applications/ColdFusion2016/config/wsconfig/2/mod_jk.so' 
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

I appreciate any help or input. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally installed Apache2 with Tomcat on my M1 and it all works.
The one thing you must do is to install a fresh Apache from Macports or HomeBrew. This is because most old installations copied from your old mac to your new one will now be in the read-only part of your file system and SIP won't let you near them. You will find weird and wonderful workarounds (apachectl told me I had to codesign mod_jk.so for example and I wasted a lot of time doing it and in the end it was pointless) and you will attempt to get the old installation to work, but trust me it's not worth it.

You will need to compile a fresh jk_module (**mod_jk.so**). This is what I did:

Download latest connector https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.48-src.tar.gz, save the .gz and unzip it.

Change directory to the `native` folder.
run `which apxs` to tell you the path to apxs for the ./configure command
The path mine gave was: `/opt/local/bin/apxs`. Use it as the path in the ./configure command below.

The commands are as follows (actually don't bother running them yet because they will fail):

1. `./configure --with-apxs=/opt/local/bin/apxs`
2. `make`

However `make` will fail with:

```
./jk_types.h:56:2: error: Can not determine the proper size for pid_t
#error Can not determine the proper size for pid_t
 ^
./jk_types.h:62:2: error: Can not determine the proper size for pthread_t
#error Can not determine the proper size for pthread_t
 ^
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [jk_ajp12_worker.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

This is a problem for M1 macs that has been fixed. So for the moment we will abandon the 1.2.48 source and download the source with the fix.
But don't delete the 1.2.48 source because the fix source is missing a few files which you will copy straight over from the 1.2.48 source.

The page to download the fix for Mac OS is here: https://github.com/apache/tomcat-connectors, which is commit `e719874` on Jun 30, 2021.

Click on the green 'Code' button and then on 'Download ZIP'.
Unzip the new source and cd to 'native'

Run the commands:

1. `./configure --with-apxs=/opt/local/bin/apxs`
2. `make`

And whenever it stops and complains that something is missing, find it in the 1.2.48 source and copy it over to the same position in the new source and try again. It will happen two or three times.

I got this error at one point:

> ```
> /home/myuser/source/mod_auth_cas/mod_auth_cas/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.15: command not found
> WARNING: 'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system.
>          You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
>          'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
>          The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
>          <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
>          It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
>          <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
>          <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
>          <http://www.perl.org/>
> make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
> ```

Then I read somewhere to run `autoreconf -f -i` (which fixed it).

When make finishes, find your nice new mod_jk.so file in the `native/apache-2.0` folder and copy it to where all your other modules are. I have a Macports installation so Homebrew is probably different, but my modules are in `/opt/local/lib/apache2/modules`.

Don't forget to add the `LoadModule` line in httpd.conf if it isn't already there:

```
LoadModule jk_module /opt/local/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so
```

You might have some trouble working out which apache2 folders contain the new install, and not an old installation - I found two other installations knocking about trying to confuse me.
My config is here: `/opt/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

`apachectl` is very useful for configuration.

`apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES` will find all the configuration files it is using. This totally saved me because it showed me that my httpd.conf file, which I had copied from elsewhere, was still pointing via 'Include' commands at other old config files in the wrong place.

`apachectl configtest` will test your config for you and print out any mistakes it finds. It pointed at 4 modules that it didn't like so I just excluded them. Though obviously read the messages carefully and google if you are not sure why apachectl doesn't like something. If it replies 'Syntax OK' you are ready to go.

This is a mysterious message I got a lot until I worked out that it was because httpd.conf was pointing at the wrong modules folder (an old install of apache2) for each module, so it was loading stuff that presumably was not compiled for 64bit

> httpd: Syntax error on line 76 of /opt/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
> Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so into server:
> dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so, 0x000A): symbol not
> found in flat namespace '_apr_stat$INODE64'

This is my launch command using the plist which Macports automatically created:
`sudo launchctl load -w /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/org.macports.apache2.plist`

And to unload:
`sudo launchctl unload /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/org.macports.apache2.plist`

run `ps ax|grep httpd` to see if it's running.

Logging: Don't forget to `sudo` to create the jk folder in `/var/log/apache2` if it doesn't already exist, otherwise apache or tomcat will have mysterious problems or won't start or something (the `/var/log/apache2/jk` folder is needed for jk.log).

Another problem cropped up just as I thought I had it made: apache
was unable to write its pid file on startup. Again this was because the position set in my config for the pid file was from the configuration on my old mac, and the position chosen was in a read-only location.
To change this you need to set the `PidFile` parameter, which I found in the following file:
/opt/local/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

and it looks like this:

```
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
#
# Note that this is the default PidFile for most MPMs.
#
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    PidFile "local/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
</IfModule>
```

Don't worry about what the IfModule thing is doing, just set the PidFile to a writeable location, which as you can see is a relative path. You may be wondering what goes in front of the `local` folder.

What goes in front is the ServerRoot parameter set in `httpd.conf`:

```
ServerRoot "/usr"
```

So my pid will be written at `/usr/local/run/apache2/httpd.pid`. I had to create the `run` and `apache2` folders.

That's about it. There are various logs that might indicate errors if you are stuck:

```
/var/log/apache2/error_log
```

And the jk.log for the apache/tomcat connector:

```
/var/log/apache2/jk/jk.log
```

And there's always the system log which just might tell you something:

```
/var/log/system.log
```

I hope very much that this helps someone. However it was very long and complicated and I have surely missed something that I did along the way, so if you come across some new problem I will see if I can help.

Comment: thank you for the detailed write-up! I went with Homebrew Apache, but might have to try Macports since I still can't get Apache to connect to Coldfusion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Running ColdFusion on a Mac is consistently a PITA. Doesn't matter if it's CF 9, 10, 11, all the way to current. Especially when you're dealing with a non-Intel based chipset. You are also trying to get an older and custom build of Toncat running on a chipset that likely isn't supported. You're also not the only one [having this issue with CF 2016 on the M1 chip](https://www.reddit.com/r/coldfusion/comments/qd7wxr/comment/hnhllta/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) (they didn't find a solution either).

Try using [CommandBox](https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox) to run CF. It will download the server as a JAR file and run it on the Glassfish servlet container (IIRC). You won't need Apache either. It's really quite simple to get up and running.

https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/embedded-server/multi-engine-support

Once you have it installed, go to your application's root folder in the CLI:

```
start cfengine=adobe@2016
```

It will download & install the server, then start the application.

Check the docs for more info.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting CommandBox; I haven't heard of it. Will try it today.

Comment: I finally got mod_jk to compile and make properly, but now there's something wrong with Coldfusion/Tomcat communicating with Apache. I keep getting the "Service Unavailable" page.

Comment: @felix822 Could you elaborate, maybe with a proper answer, on how you got mod_jk installed. I'd like to just copy from my old mac to my M1, but all apache modules are in a read-only folder now, and you can't override SIP any more so I can't add it. I could install it in a r/w folder and tell LoadModule where it is, but then you have to sign it with a bloody certificate which after two days of trying has proved impossible. Can you help at all?

Comment: @mwarren I compiled mod_jk from source. Unfortunately i did not keep notes on how exactly, but it took a lot of tries with different config settings. 

I also had to self-sign the mod_jk.so file, which I was able to do by following the steps provided here - https://blog.phusion.nl/2020/12/22/future_of_macos_apache_modules/

Comment: From what I remember, I couldn't get the source to compile with Mac's Apache so I ended up installing Homebrew's Apache. 

Then, I couldn't get my setup working properly with Homebrew Apache so I went back to Mac stock Apache, and I think that is why the mod_jk would not work ultimately.

Comment: I have contacted Adobe about the problem, but they basically said they can't help me because ColdFusion server is not yet certified for MacOS Monterey. They told me to open a request ticket for it, which I did here - https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4212692

Sorry, I couldn't be of more help. I would love to get my new laptop working so I could actually start using it for development. Maybe we can work together to make this work somehow. 

Have you tried to just migrate everything from your old laptop to the new one?

Comment: Like I said, if you just need to write code, use CommandBox. No point in waiting for official support. Mac users are the smallest portion of ACF developers, they're in no rush to officially support this OS and chip set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments @felix822. I'm stuck fast on the self-signing of the mod_jk.so module. I've seen the page you linked to and a couple of others, but no luck. I now reckon that I should be using the Apple certificate I use for developing. It all looks hunky dory but I keep getting "internal error in Code Signing subsystem" whatever I do. Which looks a lot like something Apple must sort out, so I'm going to try messaging on the developers site at Apple. Will post if I get anywhere with Apache. Can't help you with ColdFusion, which I don't use.

Comment: @Adrian J. Moreno I tried CommandBox. It was fairly easy to setup, but I had problems with my Java for some reason. I followed the directions, but my project was still throwing errors. I wish it did work me, but no luck.

Comment: @mwarren no problem at all, keep me posted on what happens. What are you using  mod_jk for if not ColdFusion?

Comment: @felix822 mod_jk is the link between Apache and Tomcat. I presume ColdFusion also uses Tomcat.

Comment: @felix822 My signing problem has been solved. But Apache still doesn't start. Here's my question and the answer: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/699126?page=1#702453022

Comment: @mwarren I didn't know about that, so thanks for the update! Hope you get Apache running.

Comment: @felix822 For what it's worth I've got it running and have answered your question with details also about how I got Apache working. Hopefully it will help someone.